# Choosing options after dynamically changing a select list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been able to remove and replace all the options in a html select list (using jQuery) but I'm not able to then select from the list. The problem appears to be connected to the "on('click')" event but I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#selectId', function() {
    var option1 = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text 1");
    var option2 = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text 2");
    $("#selectId").children().remove().end().append(option1).append(option2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
    <select name="name" id="selectId">
        <option>--- select ---</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You could use `one()` instead of `on()` but what behaviour you are expecting doesn't much make sense imho

Comment: The problem? Could you please be clearer about exactly what that is?

Comment: Are you wanting to use jQuery to select one of the options?

Comment: I have a form where users can add and remove places. The changes are then reflected in the drop-down list (which is also in the same form). Therefore, I need to dynamically generate the drop-down list to show the places and I thought the best idea would be to remove them, then add the new list every time the user clicks the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on the `select` element, you are destroying the children and replacing them with two options.  You are able to select from the list, but since you are clicking a second time, the list is destroyed once again and replaced with two brand new, identical children, with the first selected by default.  You can either replace

```
$(document).on('click', '#selectId', function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

so the change happens only on page load, or, reconsider your logic in **when** you are replacing the options (e.g. don't do this on every single click)

Answer (score 0):

In case the initialization **must** be done dynamically you can replace "on" by "one" (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)), like in

```
$(document).one('click', '#selectId', function() {
    var option1 = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text 1");
    var option2 = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text 2");
    $("#selectId").children().remove().end().append(option1).append(option2);
});
```

which should fire the event handler not more than once.

Answer (score 0):

instead of click use change event handler

```
$(document).on('change', '#selectId', function() {
    var option1 = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text 1");
    var option2 = $('<option></option>').attr("value", "option value").text("Text 2");
    $("#selectId").children().remove().end().append(option1).append(option2);
});
```